# Delphi Firemonkey TMemo - drag highlighted text?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

Can an FMX TMemo support dragging highlighted text?

Dropping a default TMemo on a 10.4 project does not allow dragging highlighted text. I cannot find a setting that would enable dragging text.

Comment: Fwiw, I'm not sureVCL does either, at least out of the box.  Anyway, have you looked at the FMX drag/drop example, it's amongst the samples, Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\DragAndDrop?  That might get you started ...

Comment: @MartynA: VCL: No, standard Windows edit controls (which is what a `TMemo` is) don't support drag and drop. However, Windows Rich Edit controls (which is what a `TRichEdit` is) does. That's proper OLE drag and drop, so you can even drag and drop to/from other applications, such as Microsoft Word or your web browser.